# Does python 3.8.2 have ensurepip? Do I need to install ensurepip to use it?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ensurepip

I'm using python 3.8.2 on ubuntu on windows 10. I'm reading an OOP pdf and I'm at the third-party libraries section. It says that pip doesn't come with python, but python 3.4 contains a useful tool called ensurepip, which  will install it: python -m ensurepip.

But when I press enter, it says no module named ensurepip

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named ensurepip
```

So I thought that I already have pip so I tried to install pygame with pip but it says there's no module named pip. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: the short answer is `python -m ensurepip` will recover

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The module [`ensurepip` is part of *Python*'s standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ensurepip.html). It should be there. You say you're on Windows, but then you show `/usr/bin/python3` in your question, which is obviously not a Windows path (rather Linux).

My assumption is that you might be using *WSL* (or *WSL2*), which is actually Linux running on Windows (without going into details). By default *WSL* runs a *Ubuntu* distribution. This distribution (and other Debian-related distributions) typically breaks up Python and its standard library in multiple pieces.

So you might need to install an additional system package, I believe it could be the `python3-venv` system package that contains the Python `ensurepip` module in your case:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

Comment: Why can't I use pip to install pygame? The sudo apt-get install python3-venv worked but I still can't use pip. Why?

Comment: running from Elementary OS I got `ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python. (...) or make sure to only use it in virtual environments.` message with some warnings in `(...)` about local system instllations. Then I create a virtual environment (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) on the project I'm working and then ran pip virtually as module (it is already there in venv). Work well also.

Comment: So, the current Python version from deadsnakes is 3.12.1. `sudo apt install python3-venv` tells me its version is 3.10.6. I think this is why I can't run ensurepip.

Comment: @ionfreeman What about `sudo apt-get install python3.12-venv`?